# EF SqlQuery IN set with parameter

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

I'm have a parameterised query which I am try to set but I get this error:

> Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '7, 8, 17, 31,
>   32, 35, 36, 37, 48, 49, 50, 51, 57, 58, 59, 60, 76, 77, 79, 80, 90,
>   91...

This is the function I use to execute the query. ItemId is an int type. I'm not sure where I'm going wrong? Perhaps the type I'm using to set the param is not what it expects, but I do not know how I do pass in a comma separated value as an int?

```
public IList<CustomEntity> GetData(string _itemIds)
{
    return m_context.Database
        .SqlQuery<CustomEntity>(
            "SELECT <column names> FROM <table name> WHERE ItemId IN (@itemIds)",
            new SqlParameter("@itemIds", _itemIds)
        )
        .ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you're passing in a string for something that is not a string - in the sql statement, it is a comma delimited list of integers.  You would need to avoid using a parameterized query in this situation and simply insert the string unaltered into the Sql statement (which is dangerous).

But why not use a LINQ to Entities query? (_itemIds would need to be an `IEnumerable<int>`)

```
m_context.CustomEntities.Where( ce => _itemIds.Contains( ce.ItemId ) ).ToList()
```

Comment: I've actually simplified the query without the inner joins and inner select. I'm pulling out lots of data also, so just using pure SQL rather than EF.